# How to write structure members at once in a file using fwrite() function?

Tags: c, data-structures, fwrite, file-handling

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct student{
    char *name;
    char *addr;
    int age;
   int clas;
 }*stu;

 int main()
 {
    FILE *fp;
    int choice,another;
    size_t recsize;
    size_t length;

   struct student *stu=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
   stu->name=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
   stu->addr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*20);

   recsize=sizeof(*stu);


           fp=fopen("student.txt","a+");
            if(fp==NULL)
               {
                 fp=fopen("student.txt","w+");
                 if(fp==NULL)
                  {
                    printf("cannot open the file");
                    exit(1);
                  }  
                }

                do
                 {
                   fseek(fp,1,SEEK_END);
                   printf("Please Enter student Details\n");

                   printf("Student Name: ");
                   scanf("%s",stu->name);

                    printf("Address: ");
                    scanf("%s",stu->addr);

                    printf("Class: ");
                    scanf("%s",&stu->clas);

                    printf("Age: ");
                    scanf("%s",&stu->age);                     

                    fwrite(stu,recsize,1,fp);

                    printf("Add another Enter 1 ?\n");
                    scanf("%d",&another);
                   }while(another==1);
                  fclose(fp);
        free(stu);


   }
```

I have code in C which has a structure **Student**. I am trying to get all structure members values from user. Memory is allocated for structure and two members ***name** and ***addr**. when I try to write those values using fwrite() function in a file Student.txt it shows random output  ( **ཀའ㌱䔀8䵁ཀའ㈱䔀1䵁** ) like this in a file and it is not in readable form. Please provide me the best way to write members of structure in file using fwrite() function.

Comment: Because you're writing the value of the pointers rather than what they contain. You're not going to be able to `fwrite` that struct in that way unless you change it to be a staticky sized allocation (array).

Comment: `scanf("%s",&stu->clas);` `scanf("%s",&stu->age);` you're writing strings into int containers, potentially corrupting memory

Comment: @DavidHoelzer ,is it possible to write what pointer is containing ? I know my code will work if *name is changed to name[20] and *addr is changed addr[20].

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you,it seems one way for code to work. Is there any other way to write using single fwrite() function rather than using fwrite() for each  member  of structure.

Comment: regarding the header file `conio.h`  1) it is not portable, 2) the posted code is not using any of the items in the header file.  it is a bad idea to include header files those contents are not being used.  Suggest removing the `#include <conio.h>` statement

Comment: when using a struct, the definition and any instance of the struct are best kept as separate statements.

Comment: when a system function returns an error indication, it is best to include the system error message in the output AND route the error message to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), the returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer. Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest removing the casting of the returned value.  Note: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 in the standard,  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect and is just cluttering the code.  Suggest removing the expression.

Comment: When calling `fopen()`, opening for append, if the file does not exist, will create the file, so if fails, opening for write+read will not fix the problem.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) consistently indent the code, Never use tabs, suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level, 3) vertically align the braces with the controlling statement 4( suggest placing literals on the left of a `==` condition, so a 'oops' like using `=` will be caught by the compiler 5) indent after every opening brace '{'  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` format specifier, always include a 'max length' modifier so the input cannot overrun the input buffer.  Such overrun results in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  When using the `%s` format specifier, unlike the other format specifiers, leading 'white space' is not consumed.  Suggest each such usage include a leading space in the format string as that will consume any leading  'white space'.

Comment: before calling `free()` for 'stu'', need to call `free()` for `stu->name` and `stu->addr`

Comment: regarding these two lines: `scanf("%s",&stu->clas);` and `scanf("%s",&stu->age);`,  The fields are of type `int`, so should use a format specifier of `%d` rather than ``%s`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: @user3629249 well thank you for every suggestion and information.It was good to know some many things.It feels like there's so many things to learn regarding coding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%d` instead of `%s` for `int`s

```
printf("Class: ");
scanf("%s",&stu->clas);

printf("Age: ");
scanf("%s",&stu->age);
```

should be

```
printf("Class: ");
scanf("%d",&stu->clas);

printf("Age: ");
scanf("%d",&stu->age);
```

And as pointed out by @David Hoelzer in comments: you're writing the value of the pointers rather than what they contain, change

```
struct student{
    char *name;
    char *addr;
```

to

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    char addr[20];
```

and delete those lines:

```
stu->name=(char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
stu->addr=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
```

Comment: I correct it, but also output is random character. since I am using pointer what is best way to write structure member in file using fwrite.

Comment: fwrite writes raw bytes, if you want formatted text use fprintf

Comment: @EttoreBarattelli Thanks for information. So how can we read those raw bytes in readable format, is there any function for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "read those raw bytes", if you want to output readable data to file you could do `fprintf(fp, "%s %s %d %d\n", stu->name, std->addr, stu->age, stu->clas);`

Comment: @EttoreBarattelli you said fwrite writes raw bytes so what i am saying, is there any function to read raw bytes in c written by fwrite().

Comment: Sure, there's [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/), but as the answer above says, you'll need to change the definitions of `name` and `addr` to be arrays instead of pointers to be able to use a single `fwrite/fread` to write/read a full structure

Comment: @EttoreBarattelli Thanks for info. I get to know some good things about file handling  but my effort was trying to accomplish everything using pointer.